# code sign error in iOS8 using ldid script

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jailbreak

I have developed an app for **jailbreak** iPhone5s running **iOS 8.1**.When I tried to sign the app using ldid script I do not get any error in Terminal.when I pushed the app to the iPhone and viewed console i see the following error:

```
Nov 10 17:27:51 iPhone installd[63] <Error>: 0x581000 -[MIExecutableBundle needsDataContainer]: Code signature not verified so we don't have entitlements for this non-user app, which means we can't determine if it needs a container.
Nov 10 17:27:52 iPhone installd[63] <Error>: 0x581000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 186: Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /Applications/TestApp.app identifier = com.bundle.s.TestApp type = 1> : 0xe800801c (Code not signed)
Nov 10 17:27:52  installd[63] <Error>: 0x581000 +[MILaunchServicesDatabaseGatherer entryForBundle:inContainer:withError:]: Failed to validate code signing for app file:///Applications/TestApp.app/ : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /Applications/TestApp.app identifier = com.bundle.s.TestApp type = 1> : 0xe800801c (Code not signed)" UserInfo=0x15d0dac0 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620388, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /Applications/TestApp.app identifier = com.bundle.s.TestApp type = 1> : 0xe800801c (Code not signed), SourceFileLine=186}
```

Even iFile and Cydia apps are getting the same error but they are running perfectly fine on the same device:

```
Nov 10 17:27:52 iPhone installd[63] <Error>: 0x581000 -[MIExecutableBundle needsDataContainer]: Code signature not verified so we don't have entitlements for this non-user app, which means we can't determine if it needs a container.
Nov 10 17:27:52 Phone installd[63] <Error>: 0x581000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]: 186: Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /Applications/iFile.app identifier = eu.heinelt.ifile type = 1> : 0xe800801c (Code not signed)
Nov 10 17:27:52 Phone installd[63] <Error>: 0x581000 +[MILaunchServicesDatabaseGatherer entryForBundle:inContainer:withError:]: Failed to validate code signing for app file:///Applications/iFile.app/ : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /Applications/iFile.app identifier = eu.heinelt.ifile type = 1> : 0xe800801c (Code not signed)" UserInfo=0x15e03980 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620388, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /Applications/iFile.app identifier = eu.heinelt.ifile type = 1> : 0xe800801c (Code not signed), SourceFileLine=186}
```

I tried the same ldid script on jailbreak iPhone5S running iOS 7.1.2 and my app was running perfectly on this jailbroken device without any code sign error.

What I am doing wrong or is it the case that ldid have'nt been updated for iOS 8.1
(I used pangu tool to jailbreak my devices and i am using Xcode ver 5.1.1)

Comment: Is your app running?   If so, why do you care about this?  Ldid produces a fake, not a valid signature.  Jailbreaking allows iOS to run the app anyway.   But console errors should be expected.

Comment: @Nate My app is running perfectly till iOS 7.1.2;The app is not running on iOS 8.1 (getting above errors) ;although i used the same ldid tool to sign code for both iOS 7.1.2 and iOS 8.1;had it been a warning i would have ignored it; but the problem is that my app is not running on iOS 8.1 due to this code sign error;although i properly signed it with ldid.

Comment: @Nate Kindly help on this issue.

Comment: guys,please help on this issue....

Comment: hi SO users,kindly give your valuable suggestion on this issue.

Comment: I have found the solution,instead of placing daemon.plist file in /System/Library/LaunchDaemon,place the file in /Library/LaunchDaemon folder